# Lotus Domino sametime retrieve online status

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, sametime

Is there any way to use the com-api to get access to online status on sametime? The data should persist in a nsf-file right? Or is this only accessible from the sametime rest api?

I only want to access the online status of every user with c#. Does anybody have any experience with this?

I have used the com-api to retrieve room-status and booking rooms so it would have been nice if its possible to still use the com-api to access online status of users!

I have looked at this document http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247037.pdf but isn't there any easier way?

Answer (score 1):

The status of users is not maintained in an NSF, and you don't use Domino/Notes APIs to access Sametime information, you would use the Sametime SDK

There used to be a Sametime COM Toolkit, but it was removed in later versions. If you get an earlier version of the Sametime Toolkit (pre 8.x I think) you'll find it in there and it will still work.

If you have a Sametime proxy server, you can query the status of users using a REST api.

Sametime Proxy, Sametime COM toolkit will all require authentication to login as a user.

The Sametime Community server toolkit, would actually be the most efficient toolkit, but it is a Java toolkit, so you'd need to wrap it to use it.